# Password hashing not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash, php-password-hash

I am trying to use password hashing using phpmysql. The issue is password_verify does not seem to work for me so far. Say, my password during registration is '123456789'. I stored it in database using

```
    password_hash('123456789', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 12));
```

And then when I enter '123456789' in the login field, it does nothing, fails.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include('db.php');        
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<p/>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login'] == 'Login') {

        $loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
        $loginPassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];

        $sqlLogin = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE email = ?");

        $sqlLogin->bind_param("s",$loginEmail);
        $sqlLogin->execute();
        $sqlLogin = $sqlLogin->get_result();
        $numrowsLogin = $sqlLogin->num_rows;

        if($numrowsLogin == 1) {
            $rowLogin = $sqlLogin->fetch_assoc(); 
            $stored_password = $rowLogin['password'];

        }
        if(password_verify($loginPassword, $stored_password)){


           header('Location: homepage.php'); 
        }else{
            echo 'invalid login';
        }      

    }         
?>


    <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
        <table style="width:500px">                        
            <tr>
                <td width="30%"><input style="width: 200px; height: 25px; border-radius: 5px;" type="text" name="loginEmail" placeholder = "Email" required/><br/></td>
            </tr>                    
            <tr>
                <td width="30%"><input style="width: 200px; height: 25px; border-radius: 5px;" type="password"  name="loginPassword" placeholder = "Password" required/><br/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input style="font-weight: bold; width: 70px; height: 25px; border-radius: 5px;" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if your query succeeds and returns a stored hash? and note that you're vulnerable to XSS attacks by using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in your form's `action`.

Comment: You need to add `exit;` after any `header('location: ...');`-call since we want to stop outputting stuff to the browser at this point.

Comment: yes, sorry for that, updated

Comment: Marc : used         error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors','1'); 

Nothing yet

Comment: @Magnus : Used that, doesn't work

Comment: I always get an invalid login message

Comment: Does this row `if($numrowsLogin == 1)` ever validate as `true`?

Comment: yep, it does indeed

Comment: Just realized that you have HTML before this block. You can't have a `header('location: ...')` after any output to the browser. Headers must be sent before any other output to the browser. You need to move your login-check to the top of the page, before the `<html>` tag and any other output.

Comment: Plus, if the password column is anything less than 60, MySQL will fail silently.

Comment: done, still doesn't work

Comment: @Fred Li : less than 60, like what? you the password length?

Comment: example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php `$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a` is 60 chars. What's yours and the length of the password column? less than 60? if so, that's the problem. Too short and your code failed silently because of it and you need to start over with a new hash after altering the column's length. @BishwaroopChakraborty

Comment: @BishwaroopChakraborty reload my above comment, I edited it a few times. I will delete this comment shortly. Ping me back if that's what the problem was.

Comment: @Fred Li : thanks, that worked for me. My password column length in the database was 50. updated it and works now, thankyou once again!!

Comment: @BishwaroopChakraborty I'll post an answer then and you can mark it as solved. you're welcome, glad I was of help.

Comment: Please read the comments in the answer by @fred. You will never again have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

> *@Fred Li : thanks, that worked for me. My password column length in the database was 50. updated it and works now, thankyou once again!! – Bishwaroop Chakraborty"*

As discussed in commments:

Example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

`$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a` is 60 chars.

Your password column's length is less than 60 and that's the problem.

It's too short and your code *failed silently* because of it and you need to start over with a new hash after altering the column's length.

- The manual says that 255 is a good bet.

Notes:

Pay attention to other comments left in regards to XSS injection.

Here are a few good articles:

- [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

and to add `exit;` after header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute.

Comment: imo, just use a `varchar` field of 255. The cost is one byte extra and this fault would never have happened. imo, never use exact length character / varchar fields in a database.

Comment: @RyanVincent Exactly; I wrote a short note about the manual saying it's "a good bet" ;-) Thanks for your comment btw.

Comment: Sorry, @fred, I meant it for the OP ;-/ finger trouble

Comment: @RyanVincent No worries :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the event that new comers are still getting errors with this after verifying sufficient data storage (for example:`varchar255`)

Be sure to use the unhashed `string` in the verify-password function.

```
verify_password($unhashed-string, $hashed-string)
```

I lost a few hours sleep passing a hashed `string` into first parameter of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am using blowfish algorithm for hashing password. It has run successfully for me, so you can try this.

```
<?php

$pass = "test678";

$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);  //password_hash() function hash given password

$matchpass = "test678";

$match = password_verify($matchpass, $hash); // password_verify() function hash given boolean value if password can match so it return 1 otherwise 0

if ($match == true) {
    echo "Password can match successfully......";
} else {
    echo "Password cannot match please try again.";
}

?>
```

OUTPUT:

Password can match successfully......